# Facebook SDK for Android, Re-Login after fresh installing issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just started with Facebook SDK for android.
I built a simple log in app, but something is very bad.
In my app, I log in using ***LoginManager*** and if the log in was successfuly done - I get an ***Access Token***. Simple and great. This action also accept the permissions of my app for the the user that just logged in using my app.
But, if I uninstall the app (my app) from my phone (without log out), and then install it again
and try to log in again, I get an
***"Invalid key hash. The key hash {blablablabla} does not match any stored key hashes. ..."***
error shown in some facebook activity.

So, the user accept the app permissions in the past,
and get some Access Token. But when he try to log in again after a fresh app installing, it does not work and show error.
I think it's because the user accepted the permissions in the past with
some Access Token, and now, when the Access Token is NULL (because of a fresh installing), the facebook sdk does not accept that.

I just need my app to recognize that the user already has permissions,
and do not log in. So I tried to check if the user has permissions:

```
         new GraphRequest(
                **{{{Access Token is missing}}}**,
                "/me/permissions",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() 
                {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) 
                    {
                        if( response.getError() != null )
                        {
                            //user has no permissions, do login
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //user has permissions, do not login
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
```

but because it's a fresh installing app (so the user has no Access Token), the Access Token is missing.
So, I tried to create a new Access Token (somehow):

```
        AccessToken.createFromNativeLinkingIntent(getIntent(), getString(R.string.facebook_app_id), new AccessTokenCreationCallback() 
    {
        public void onSuccess(AccessToken token) 
        {
            AccessToken.setCurrentToken(token);
        }

        public void onError(FacebookException error) 
        {
        }
    });
```

but it's does not work. onError(FacebookException error) is always invoked.
How to solve that?

**EDIT :
if I succeed to check if the user has permissions, so then I can easily remove the current permissions and then make a new log in,

and that's will solve my problem.**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you generate the keyhash and give that value to your Facebook Developer Account?

Comment: You need to [get the key hash from your compiling machine](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash) and save it in the Android section of your [Facebook app's settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/89000000000000/settings/)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by placing the key hash they gave you in the [blah blah] space and add it to your key hashes in facebook developers for this app